# how to access the value of a symbol when it is referred to by another symbol

Tags: clojure

This is a simple example to show what i mean:

```
> (def code "(def some-code [1 2 3])")
> (def data (read-string code))
> (def var  (eval data))
```

using println:

```
> (println var)
;; => #'example.system/some-code

> (println some-code)
;; => [1 2 3]
```

now that `var` contains a reference to `some-code`, how do i retrieve `[1 2 3]` if i have `var`? its usage would be somthing like this function:

```
> (return var) ;=> [1 2 3]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be to use [var-get](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/var-get)

```
user=> (var-get var)
[1 2 3]
```